# how to change how the code writes the data in my file

Tags: python, layout

when i run the code it leaves the data looking like this in the .txt file:

```
s,['["[\'2\']"', " '3']", '10']
```

i need it to look like this:

```
s,2,3,10
```

this is my code:

```
pname = input("What is your name")
correct = input("What is your score")
SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

try: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "r+")
except IOError: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "w+") # File not exists
actualScoresTable = []
for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")

        for index, score in enumerate(tmp[1:]):
            tmp[1+index] = str(score)

        actualScoresTable.append({
                                "name": tmp[0],
                                "scores": tmp[1:],
                                })
scoresFile.close()

new = True
for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
if record["name"] == pname:
    actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(correct)
    if len(record["scores"]) > MAX_SCORES:
        actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].pop(0) # OR del actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]
    new = False
    break
if new:
actualScoresTable.append({
                            "name": pname,
                            "scores": [correct],
                            })

scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
for record in actualScoresTable:

for index, score in enumerate(record["scores"]):
    record["scores"][index] = str(score)
       scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"],(record["scores"])) )
scoresFile.close()
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are down voting my post

Comment: I think it would really help if you explained what exactly your code is supposed to do and how. Showing you've tried to debug yourself (e.g. printing the variables contents). It is usually appreciated to exactly explain what you don't understand (other that "I don't understand my own code").

Comment: My code is supposed to only record the latest 3 results for each student.

Comment: @PatJ If the students name is already in the file it will add the score to the name. Thanks to the answer i have the layout i want but it doesnt add results to that students name if it is already there, it just overwrites the score and puts the new one.

Comment: Please add an example of a couple of items from ```actualScoresTable``` to your post.  Also , Please add an example of a couple of lines of ```Class1.txt```

Comment: @wwii There isnt anything in actualScoresTable and i want the data to be written into the .txt file so there isnt any data in that also

Comment: Ahh well, I guess I meant - You have a data file, ```Class1.txt``` that you are reading from - please add an example of a couple of lines from that file to your post.  When you read that file you process it and end up with an intermediate result which is ```actualScoresTable``` - please post a few items from that intermediate result ... just after ```scoresFile.close()``` add ```print(actualScoresTable[:3]``` and show us that.

Comment: @wwii which scoresFile.close()

Comment: @wwii if i put it after the one at the end of the code it says unexpected EOF while parsing. If i put it after the one in the middle it says that 'new' is an invalid syntax

Comment: @wwii sorry wasnt looking hard enough here is what it said

Comment: [{'scores': ['5'], 'name': 'f'}, {'scores': ['10'], 'name': 'f'}, {'scores': ['5'], 'name': 'f'}]

Comment: @wwii sorry thats wrong it looks like this

Comment: @wwii [{'scores': ['4', '10'], 'name': 'f'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
     scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"],(record["scores"])) ) 


scoresFile.close()
```

you have the list record["scores"] being sent to string, remember, you need the values record["scores"][index] recorded.

```
pname = input("What is your name")
correct = input("What is your score")
SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

try: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "r+")
except IOError: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "w+") # File not exists
actualScoresTable = []
for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")

        for index, score in enumerate(tmp[1:]):
            tmp[1+index] = str(score)

        actualScoresTable.append({
                                "name": tmp[0],
                                "scores": tmp[1:],
                                })
scoresFile.close()

new = True
for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
    if record["name"] == pname:
        actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(correct)
    if len(record["scores"]) > MAX_SCORES:
        actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].pop(0) # OR del actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]
    new = False
    break
if new:
    actualScoresTable.append({
                            "name": pname,
                            "scores": [correct],
                            })

scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
for record in actualScoresTable:
    for index, score in enumerate(record["scores"]):
        record["scores"][index] = str(score)
        scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"],(record["scores"][index])) )
scoresFile.close()
```

Here is some code that does what you want to do.

```
pname = input("What is your name")
correct = input("What is your score")
SCORE_FILENAME  = "Class1.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

try: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "r+")
except IOError: scoresFile = open('Class1.txt', "w+") # File not exists

actualScoresTable = dict()

for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
        actualScoresTable[tmp[0]]=tmp[1:]
scoresFile.close()


if pname not in actualScoresTable.keys():
        actualScoresTable[pname] = [correct]
else:
        actualScoresTable[pname].append(correct)
        if MAX_SCORES < len(actualScoresTable[pname]):
                actualScoresTable[key].pop(0)


scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
for key in actualScoresTable.keys():
        scoresFile.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, ','.join(actualScoresTable[key])))
scoresFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. but now when i add a score it overrites the current score for that person and puts the new score e.g

Comment: a,2 and then when i run the test agian a,4 instead of a,2,4

Comment: a2 -> a,2 (newline) a,4

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: i copied and pasted the code into a new file and ran it. it puts  the results onto a new line but i want the layout to look like this a,1,2,3 not a1 (newline) a2 (newline) a3

Comment: read the last post I made, as I have tested it, and it works, and compare to your code. when you do, maybe you'll see what your code is doing wrong.

Comment: Like I said earlier, str(score) will convert a list (which is what score is) to the string version of it, so '[1,2,3...]

Comment: @wwii  How do i define key

Comment: @Jossef Harush How do i define key

Answer (score 1):

**First**, the data you have in `record["scores"]`

```
['["[\'2\']"', " '3']", '10']
```

- **`list`**

  - `["[\'2\']"` - *string*
  - `'3']` - *string*
  - `10` - *string*

not all characters are plain numbers ( you have characters like,, `'`, `[`, `"` ).

**this needs to be treated**, my guess is that the problem is where you add new items to the `record["scores"]` list.

---

### **Let's assume that we have nothing but numbers in `record["scores"]`**

e.g.

```
 record["name"] = 's'
 record["scores"] = ['2', '3', '10']
```

now this should work as you requested

```
items = list()
items.append(record["name"])
items.extend(record["scores"]) # which is list, so it should work
scoresFile.write(','.join(items) + '\n')
```

will output

```
s,2,3,10
```

---

## Edit: added example

```
SCORE_FILENAME = 'scores.txt'

# -------------------------------
# TODO: inputs to construct `actualScoresTable`

actualScoresTable = [
{ "name": "Millan", "scores": ['1', '2', '3']}, 
{ "name": "Obama", "scores": ['55', '11', '32']},
]

# -------------------------------
# This is how you should output it to a file as you requested

with open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") as scoresFile:
    for record in actualScoresTable:
        items = list()
        items.append(record["name"])
        items.extend(record["scores"])
        scoresFile.write(','.join(items) + '\n')
```

will output into `scores.txt` the following

```
Millan,1,2,3
Obama,55,11,32
```

Comment: nest this snippet in where

Comment: what  if i want the user to enter the scores. And also if i was to add another score would it show the last 3 results or all 4 results.

Comment: please help me with this my deadline is next week

Comment: @MilanLad, then you need to modify the list (google it, you will find many examples)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate list items to a string:

```
>>> a = ['4', '10']
>>> ','.join(a)
'4,10'
>>> ' | '.join(a)
'4 | 10'
>>> ' * '.join(a)
'4 * 10'
>>>
```

Assuming `actualScoresTable` looks like this:

```
actualScoresTable = [{'scores': ['4', '10'], 'name': 'f'},
                     {'scores': ['8', '3'], 'name': 'g'}]
```

write to the file in the desired format like this:

```
# a couple of helpers for code readability
import operator
name = operator.itemgetter('name')
scores = operator.itemgetter('scores')

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for record in actualScoresTable:
        line = '{},{}\n'.format(name(record), ','.join(scores(record)))
        print(line)
        f.write(line)

>>> 
f,4,10

g,8,3

>>>
```